# High CPU Usage by "root" User in Ubuntu VPS server

Tags: linux, ssh, cpu

My server was working fine until last week, until it seems someone changed my SSH password. After this when I checked the CPU usage, it always `160-190%` on executing `top` command. Some users told that sites are going down many times due to this.

I'm wondering how CPU usage becomes more than 100%. Usually, my CPU usage was always under 10%, may go up to 20% on high traffic. It will be used be `www-data`.

I am SSH'ing in using Putty, and this is what I see:

[image]

Server configuration:

- **OS**: Ubuntu
- **Web Server**:  Nginx
- **RAM:** 2GB
- **Control Panel:** Ajenti

Comment: Nuke it from orbit and start over. Restore only known-intact files. See [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server) for more advice. Take it off the Internet as soon as reasonably possible -- you don't know what it's doing.

Comment: What is `vfqqmxnbov`?  Google does not know it.  Did you try killing it or to find its parent?

Comment: Its probably a Bot.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest taking the server offline *immediately*. Backup everything (When this happened to me, I just tarballed up the entire contents of my server and downloaded it), then run it through a virus scan to see if it picks up what's the issue.

*Rebuild* the server from scratch. "But I don't know how someone have changed by ssh root password" is a *terrible* thing and you don't want that. Don't bother 'fixing' it. Check through any user data before copying it back over. I'd use a modified version of [my server duplication answer on SF here](https://serverfault.com/questions/540885/how-do-i-duplicate-a-server/540888#540888) -checking to see if there's any dodgy users too. Compare any config files from the compromised machine with a fresh copy and make any necessary changes by hand.

While many VPSes tend to give you a root account by default, they arn't secured properly. Ideally I'd *disable* the root account for ssh and have an admin account (which is how ubuntu is setup by default), and have *key based authentication* turned on and mandatory.

I'd *discourage* the use of a control panel, especially for a single use system. Setting up things by hand means you're better equipped to document and rebuild if bad things happen.

Comment: ok. I will move the server to a temporary one

But how to i run a virus scan?

Comment: In my case, I copied over an archive of files to a windows box (oh, the irony) and scanned there.